# jquery popup loads when refresh, why?

Tags: jquery, jsp

the below is the code for popup and my account is the submit button.the jquery popup loads when we refresh the page and i am able to see the popup

```
<div id="myAccount">
<div class="btnPackage">
<c:url value="/logout" var="mobeeLogoutUrl"/>
<c:url value="/changePass" var="changePassword"></c:url>
<c:url value="/paymentDetails" var="payment"></c:url>
<div id="popup_content" > 
<p align="center" class="popText"><label class="titleText">My Account</label></p>
<hr>
<p  class="popText"><a href="${mobeeLogoutUrl}" onclick="hide('myAccount')" class="fbText1">Logout</a></p>
<hr>
<p class="popText"><a href="${changePassword}" onclick="hide('myAccount')" class="fbText1">Change PIN</a></p>
<hr>
<p class="popText"><a href="${payment}" onclick="hide('myAccount')" class="fbText1">View Account</a></p>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="hide('myAccount')" class="cancel" style="color:#fff;">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What in the code tells that it shouldn't be displayed ?

Comment: in the above code i have my account button if i click on that button my popup should pop out on the mobile screen but it is happening only when refresh the page and click on my account button